# Console output with WinAPI WriteConsole

Tags: c, winapi, console

I'm trying to do hello world with winapi functions. It's kind of working but I would love to have it done the proper way.

So i got code like this:

```
int main(){
    HANDLE std_out;
    int i;
    char *error_msg;

    std_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if(std_out == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        MessageBox(NULL,"stdout not available","Error",MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }

    AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);

    if(!WriteConsoleA(std_out,"hhh\n",4,&i,NULL)){
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,NULL,GetLastError(),0,&error_msg,4,NULL);
        MessageBox(NULL,error_msg,"Error",MB_OK);
    }

    return 42;
}
```

Also I'm a little bit experimenting so I link with /entry:main /subsystem:windows

the output is then like:

```
%PATH_TO_WORKING_DIR%>hhh(CRLF)
```

then it waits until I press RETURN and then the program terminates, which as you probably agree is very crapy "hello world". Any ideas how to get rid of that PWD and necessity to press return are very welcomed, thx for reading.

Comment: You probably want to read up on the return value convention of `main`.

Comment: You are going to need to either use start.exe /wait yourapp.exe to start your program, call AllocConsole instead of AttachConsole or set the subsystem to console.

Comment: @MikeKwan: that is not the issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a GUI application that you force to act like a console application. I'm guessing cmd.exe (or whatever the parent is) is getting confused as you both think you "own" stdout.

Link with /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE and the problems should go away (and then you don't need /ENTRY or the call to AttachConsole)

If you actually want a GUI/Console hybrid, you need to call AllocConsole when there is no console (Started from Explorer etc)

Comment: You can get a GUI/console hybrid simply by using `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` with `CreateWindow` too.

Comment: Yea I actually should have said that I don't want any libc present, I want to set it up on my own. But whatever it works now, changing the subsystem helped, kept my entry though :). Anyway, you mentioned something in manner that I can't manage stdout as I did in the code, is there something I'm missing/doing wrong? AllocConsole, tried out, worked as well, cool function :), thx

Comment: main is not the real entry point on windows, for a console app the name is mainCRTStartup when using the MS toolchain (See http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S569.aspx )